# VS 2008 and Team Explorer- checked out files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

how to search for files checked out by other users in vs 2008 Team Explorer. I can search for all the files checked out in a project in Visual Source Safe by doing a search, Is there a similar functionality implemented in team explorer? Right now I have to click on every folder and see if files from that folder are checked out by any one else or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this command into the "External Tools..." list of VS.

Tools  >> External Tools…
Select “Add” and enter the following:
Title:  “View all checked-out files”
Command:  “tf.exe”
Arguments:  “status $(ProjectDir) /user:* /recursive “
Check “Use Output window”
Un-check “Prompt for arguments”
Select “OK”.

Answer (score 2):

Get the TFS Power Tools - they integrate into the Team Explorer view.  You'll get a list of people on the team.  You can right click the team members and see their current changesets.

You can check out the TFS Power Tools on the Microsoft site [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx) - the October 2008 edition has the Team Members functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The Attrice TFS Sidekicks can be used to get some info not displayed in VS. I believe the Status view will display what you are after: http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs

Answer (score 1):

Installing the (free) Team Foundation Server Power Tools from Microsoft adds a number of extra features to Source Control Explorer including the ability to right click on a folder and choose "Find In Source Control".

You can download Team Foundation Server Power Tools from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

You can run TF.exe status command statement to get list of files checked out under specific project.  you can also search based on user name..

here is the link for more information.

http://patelshailesh.com/index.php/how-to-get-the-list-of-currently-checked-out-files-in-tfs

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible from Team Explorer.
You can do it from command line using [TF STATUS](http://blogs.vertigosoftware.com/teamsystem/archive/2006/07/24/3125.aspx) command.